# How to unsubscribe messaging/voice webhook to stop receiving events occurred in a number?

Tags: twilio

In Twilio, after we register a webhook URL in an active number, we'll be able to get event notifications whenever events occour in the registered number depending on the type of webhook we registered (Voice/SMS).

The registration of the webhook can be achieved via REST API. Similarly is there any API to stop the webhook notification? Else how should we handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same API, [incomingPhoneResource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource), would be used do the same. You should be able to create, read, update and delete the configured webhooks for voice and SMS phone number configurations this way.

Comment: From this API, we can delete an IncomingPhoneNumber. But if we want to keep the number and only want to delete the webhooks, is there any way? Updating the URL to an empty string can work. But I would like to know the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Using the API to update the respective field to an empty string is the correct way.


```client.incomingPhoneNumbers('PNd3968c17dac83ed7538f3da1fabcdef')
  .update({smsUrl: ''})
  .then(incoming_phone_number => console.log(incoming_phone_number));```